# Update WPF controls at run time

Tags: .net, wpf, controls, multithreading, runtime

I'm trying to write a WPF application that will update a set of text boxes and labels at run time using threads but the problem is that when ever a thread tries to update the text boxes and labels I get the following error: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."  Is it possible to update the control at run time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you have to update the UI elements in the UI thread using [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx).

Example in C#: Instead of

```
myTextBox.Text = myText;
```

use

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => myTextBox.Text = myText));
```

VB.NET (before version 4) does not support anonymous methods, so you'll have to workaround it with an anonymous function:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(Function() UpdateMyTextBox(myText))

...

Function UpdateMyTextBox(ByVal text As String) As Object
    myTextBox.Text = text
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

---

Alternatively, you can start your background threads using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class, which support updates in the UI through the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events: Both events are raised in the UI thread automatically. An example for using BackgroundWorker can be found here: [SO question 1754827](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754827/wpf-update-ui-from-viewmodel-class-mvvm-pattern/1754848#1754848).

Answer (score 2):

Controls in WPF have a `Dispatcher` property on which you can call `Invoke`, passing a delegate with the code you'd like to execute in the context of the GUI thread.

```
myCheckBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                             () => myCheckBox.IsChecked = true);
```