# Keeping boolean values in sync between two threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In one thread (thread2) I have changed a value e.g.

```
CheckSuccess = false;
```

Now the main thread (thread1 - GUI / Form) does not pickup the change, how would it be possible to "propogate" the changes around all threads?

I was under the impression that threads should manipulate the data, not work on seperate instances (unless told to do so)

Comment: Is it marked as [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

Comment: Does the main thread actively monitor the boolean, or become somehow aware that is changed?

Comment: The backgroundworker offers Completed and ProgressChanged events to deal with this.

Comment: Is CheckSuccess is a property or a public field?

Comment: Are you sure the main thread and background thread are looking at the same variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545030/keeping-boolean-values-in-sync-between-two-threads/8545045#8545045

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a [Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). To avoid this you should synchronize an access to the shared variables.

- If CheckSuccess is a field - try out marking it by `volatile` keyword.
- If `CheckSuccess` is a property (which will be translated to a method call) you can use [lock() statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

  ```
  private static readonly object stateLock = new object();
  lock (stateLock)
  {
      // access a shared variable here
      CheckSuccess  = false;
  }
  ```
- If `CheckSuccess` is a property of UI control and you want changing it from a worker thread - you should use special techniques to push changes from a worker to the UI thread, it depends on which framework you are using WinForms of WPF.

  - WinForms - [How to update GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661561/485076)
  - WPF - [Update WPF controls at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2243016/485076)

**PS:**
Also if you have multiple threads reading a value and few threads writing (basically reads more often than writing) you may find useful [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx)

Comment: It won't solve the race condition, since it's just about writing an atomic value. Just incorrect order of execution.

Comment: @Dykam : I believe CheckSuccess is a property which translated to a method call, but need to clarify perhaps this is bad naming for a field

Answer (score 0):

I normally use Interlocked methods such as [Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337971.aspx). This is much simpler than using a locking object and it's guaranteed to be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely compiler optimizations causing the caching of the boolean value in a CPU register. Declaring it as `volatile` should solve your problem.